# write code to find square-root using bisection method in c++?

Tags: c++, square-root, bisection

Bisection is as far as i know narrowing your search and reach the specific value in interval. please give me a sample of that how to make a generic code to find square-root. the way i think is taking three variables low, mid, high. high = userinput, low = 0, mid (low + high) /2, problem is how to how to change values then.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework for you. **YOU** write some code. then we'll maybe try help fixing it.

Comment: If you have no attempt we can't help you, we aren't doing your homework for you.

Comment: I would hope if you plan to continue in studying coding that you actually take the time to learn and understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int val;
   cout << "Enter the number: ";
   cin >> val;

   if( val< 0) {
      cout<< "According to my maths its not possible." << endl;
   } else {
      float low = 0, high = val;
      float mid = (low  + high)/2;
      int c = 0;

      while (c != 1) {
         if(mid * mid = val) {
            cout << "Square root is: " << mid <<endl;
            c = 1;
         } else {
            if(mid * mid > val) {
               high = mid;
               mid = (low + high)/2;
            } else {
               low = mid;
               mid = (low + high)/2;
            }
         }
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user2966111 Please make an effort to really understand why this works. You won't ever be successfull in your class if you just copy paste the solution.

Comment: what the explanation behind "c=0" and "while (c != 1)"?

Comment: c=0 is initial condition and c!=1 is to check condition, while it's true it will exit the loop ( c=1)

Comment: For not perfect square root the loop will run for ever!

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the we are looking for `sqrt(N)`

As described [here](http://www.mathpath.org/Algor/squareroot/algor.square.root.binary.htm), you have to find the average of LOW and HIGH, if square of average is greater than `N`, we change the high value with the average we just found, if it is less than `N`, we change the low value with the average. And we repeat the steps as many times to satisfy the required precision.